# Check if Vec contains all elements from another Vec

Tags: vector, collections, rust

There is a method [contains](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.contains) that can be used to check if a particular element exists in a `Vec`. How to check if all elements from a `Vec` are contained in another `Vec`? Is there something more concise than iterating manually and checking all elements explicitly?

Comment: [`other_vector.iter().all(|e| vector.contains(e))`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78290eaafe55cb41517aeee6d40dbcff) doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: An other alternative would be to load both in a [HashSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) or [BTreeSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html) and use is_subset/is_superset. That would have higher constant overhead, but it should be linear rather than quadratic which is probably a good idea if the collections are quite large.

Comment: @mcarton actually, but almost all languages I have been worked with had something out-of-the-box. So I asked in case I missed something and there's some method for that in Rust.

Comment: Really? I don't know a single language supporting a subset check for a vector-like datastructure out of the box. For set datastructures, sure, but not for a vector.

Comment: @SvenMarnach At least [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-)

Comment: I'm indeed not familiar with Java's standard library.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have two main choices:

- naively check each element from one vector to see if it's in the other. This has time complexity O(n^2) but it's also very simple and has low overhead:

  ```
  assert!(b.iter().all(|item| a.contains(item)));
  ```
- create  a set of all of elements of one of the vectors, and then check if elements of the other are contained it it. This has O(n) time complexity, but higher overhead including an extra heap allocation:

  ```
  let a_set: HashSet<_> = a.iter().copied().collect();
  assert!(b.iter().all(|item| a_set.contains(item)));
  ```

Which one is "better" will depend on your requirements. If you only care about speed, the better choice will still depend on the number of elements in your vectors, so you should test both with realistic data. You could also test with a `BTreeSet`, which has different performance characteristics from `HashSet`.

---

Here are some rough benchmarks ([source](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a0a94d43f262658529ee3e168af2c4a1)) for how the implementations vary with the size of the input. In all tests, `b` is half the size of `a` and contains a random subset of `a`'s elements:

| Size of `a` | `Vec::contains` | `HashSet::contains` | `BtreeSet::contains` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 14 | 386 | 327 |
| 100 | 1,754 | 3,187 | 5,371 |
| 1000 | 112,306 | 31,233 | 88,340 |
| 10000 | 2,821,867 | 254,801 | 728,268 |
| 100000 | 29,207,999 | 2,645,703 | 6,611,666 |

Times in nanoseconds.

The naive `O(n^2)` solution is fastest when the number of elements is small. The overhead of allocating a `HashSet` or `BTreeSet` is overshadowed by the impact of the number of comparisons when the size is more than about 200. `BTreeSet` is mostly a lot slower than `HashSet`, but is slightly faster when the number of elements is *very* small.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sorted vectors, you can do the search in linear time:

```rust
    let mut vec = vec![0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 3, 5, 1, 0];
    let mut v = vec![1, 4, 3, 3, 1];

    vec.sort_unstable();
    v.sort_unstable();

    // Remove duplicates elements in v
    v.dedup();

    let mut vec_iter = vec.iter();
    assert!(v.iter().all(|&x| vec_iter.any(|&item| item == x)));
```

Reference: C++ has [std::includes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) which does exactly that.

Comment: This will give incorrect results if `v` has repeated elements - or at least _different_ results. It is correct if the requirement is that the other vec contains the same number of each item.

Comment: I have edited my answer to handle the case of duplicate elements in `v`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the other answers here: depending on how your `Vec`s are set up, you may be able to save yourself some comparison by comparing their lengths. The vec `a` can only contain `b` if its length is greater than or equal to `b`'s. (AND `b` has no duplicates.)

```rust
assert!(a.len() >= b.len());
```

Answer (score -4):

You could also sort the vectors and then test them for equality:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v1 = vec![2, 3, 1];
    let mut v2 = vec![3, 1, 2];
    
    v1.sort();
    v2.sort();

    assert_eq!(v1, v2);
}
```

Comment: Note that they're asking about subsetting, not just equality e.g. `v1` might have just `1` and `3` but not `2`.